# Velocity and Acceleration

Tags: calculus, physics

I'm currently studying applications of calculus to the physical world in mathematics. I don't understand how a particle with zero velocity can have a positive acceleration. If the particle is at rest, then how can it be accelerating?

Comment: throw a ball up in the air. what is happening when the ball reaches its maximum height?

Comment: Accelerating means its changing its velocity. Imagine a car driving forward at some speed, when suddenly, the driver switches the gear-stick to reverse. The car will have to apply a force opposite to the direction that it is moving, until it finally stops (where the velocity is 0).

The car is only at a zero velocity for an instantaneous amount of time, because the car is still in the reverse-gear and so it will start moving backwards.

Think of positive/negative acceleration as how fast the car is changing its speed per second

Comment: if it is accelerating, a particle can only have $v=0$ for an instant while transitioning between positive and negative velocities.

Answer (score 2):

The key fact that makes this possible is the fact that position, velocity and acceleration are all vector quantities. Even if the magnitudes of these quantities is zero, the **direction** in a given coordinate system is not zero. Abel hints at this in his comment above-when a ball is thrown up in the air and reaches it's maximum height, the velocity is 0, but the ball has begun to change direction at the inflection point of the parabolic arc. As a result,acceleration is not 0 as the ball has begun to change direction downwards without changing velocity. In mathematical terms,think about the second derivative test for constructing the graph in one dimension. Critical points occur where the first derivative with respect to the independent variable is 0 at the given point,yet the second derivative is nonzero since whether it's positive or negative determines the direction of the graph. It's the exact same thing in this case-the velocity is the first derivative of position with respect to time and acceleration is the second derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this, 
We start with the velocity being $-10$ (I.e. Going in reverse), and we accelerate at a constant rate of $2$. 
Eventually you reach a point where your velocity is $0$, and we start going forward after.